# How should I phrase mathematically correctly the following set theory statement?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number.
$A$ = {$k : k∈Z+, 1≤k≤p$}
I want to list every composite positive integer from 1 to $p$ in a set called $B$, with a notation, that it is a subset of $A$. 
For example if $p=7$, then $A$ = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
Therefore $B$ = {4,6}
Is the following mathematically correct, or if not, how should I formulate it ?
Let $B∈A$ = {every composite number in $A$}

Thanks.

Comment: Some unsolicited advice: You seem more concerned with mathematical formalism ("mathematically correct") than clarity. There's nothing wrong with writing "Let B be the set of all composite integers in the interval 1 to $p$."

Comment: Thanks, great advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $B \in A$ would mean $B$ is an element of $A$ which is not the case.

$B=\{x \in A:x \text{ is composite}\}$

Comment: Thanks, I get it.
One additional thing, if I want to index the elements of B, how should I do it?
Like 1 to |B|, what is the correct way?

Comment: Hmmm... a set is unordered. For finite set, perhaps you can write let $b_i$ be the distinct elements of $B$ where $i=1, \ldots, |B|$.

Comment: Yeah, I like that, makes sense, these sets are indeed finite. Thanks

Comment: So, does it look ok?
p is a prime number.
Let $A$ = {k : k ∈ Z+, 1≤k≤p}
Let $a(i)$ be the distinct prime elements of $A$, where i is the ith prime in $A$.
As $A$ is finite, therefore $i$ is finite.
Let $B$  = {$a(i)$ ∈ $A$ : $a(i)$ is prime, $i=1,…|B|$}

Comment: Hmmm... looks strange. What about let $B =\{x \in A: \text{some condition }\}$ and we let $b_i$ the $i$-th smallest element of $B$.

Comment: yeah, sounds great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just happened to notice this question right now. In case you might still be interested in receiving answers, here is a very rigorous suggestion.

First of all define the set:
$$\mathbb{P}\colon=\{p \in \mathbb{N}|\ p \geqslant 2 \wedge (\forall k)((k \in \mathbb{N} \wedge k \mid p) \Rightarrow (k=1 \vee k=p))\}$$
of all natural prime numbers (from a strictly algebraic point of view, $-2$ is also a prime number, but that would be another discussion).

Having declared this set, specifying all the composite elements of an arbitrary subset $M \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ will of course depend on the precise definition of compositeness. In what follows I will adopt the standard that $m \in \mathbb{N}$ is composite if $m \geqslant 2$ and $m \notin \mathbb{P}$. It follows that the set of all composite numbers in $M$ can be expressed very succinctly as $M \setminus (\mathbb{P} \cup \{0, 1\})$.